# when is a map of analytic Brauer groups induced by inclusion injective?

Tags: complex-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, brauer-groups

A theorem of Auslander and Goldman states that for a regular integral scheme $X$ the inclusion of the generic point $\mathrm{Spec}\ K \to X$ induces an injective map $Br(X) \to Br(\mathrm{Spec}\ K)$.

Let $U \subset X$ be a dense open subset of a complex analytic space. In which situations (i.e. under which conditions on $U$ and $X$) is it known that the map $Br(X) \to Br(U)$ is injective?

Comment: Certainly that map is not usually injective.  By the Grauert-Oka principle, the Brauer group of a Stein manifold equals the topological Brauer group of that manifold.  So, for instance, injectivity fails for the inclusion of $\mathbb{C}^2$ into $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

Comment: Dear Jason, what is the statement of Grauert-Oka principle that you refer to? I can see why a cohomological analytic Brauer group would be equal to cohom. topological Brauer group, but how do I prove the equality for "true" Brauer groups?

Comment: @Dima: Here is a reference.

MR0098198 (20 #4660)
Grauert, Hans
Holomorphe Funktionen mit Werten in komplexen Lieschen Gruppen. (German)
Math. Ann. 133 1957 450–472.
32.00

Every element of the "true" Brauer group has associated (in more than one way) a principal $\mathbf{PGL}_n$-bundle which has a section if and only if the element is zero.  Grauert's theorem proves that this bundle has an analytic section if and only if it has a continuous section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got a bit long for a comment, so here's an answer. The answer is it is almost never injective. In general, for compact $X$, $Br(X)$ is infinite (at least if $H^2(X,O_X)\neq 0$), while $Br(U)$ is finite if $U$ is Stein. I'm not sure how Jason's comment above gives a counterexample, as both $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2$ have trivial analytic Brauer group. But, you could do something similar. Let $X$ be an K3 surface, and let $U\subset X$ be a Stein submanifold. Then, $U$ has the homotopy type of a $2$-dimensional CW-complex, so by the Oka principle, the analytic Brauer group of $U$ is zero. But, the analytic Brauer group of $X$ is pretty big (it's a copy of several $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. For more details about this sort of thing, see Section 2 of Schroer's 2005 paper on topological methods for analytic Brauer groups.

Comment: @Benjamin, thank you for you answer. To clarify: why does U have a homotopy of a 2-dimensional complex?

Comment: This is closely related to the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, as proven by Andreotti and Frankel: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0177422. Specifically, Theorem 1 of their paper says that an $n$-dimensional stein manifold $X$ has no integral cohomology in degree higher than $n$ and that $\Hoh_n(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free. In particular, this holds for smooth affine complex $n$-folds, from which they deduce the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem. It's a 5-page paper worth looking at.

Comment: Sorry, that should read $H_n(X,\mathbb{Z})$.